# Compile time Error in C code [Returning an array pointer from function]

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, *ptr; 
    ptr = func();
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        printf("%d", ptr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int * func()
{
    int *pointer;
    pointer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*20);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        pointer[i] = i+1; 
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

ERROR:
Conflicting type of func.
Warning:
Assignment makes Pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: you should also check the value `malloc` returns for `NULL`

Answer (score 7):

Because you're calling `func()` without first declaring it. This causes the compiler to assume it's going to return `int`, but then you store that integer in a pointer which is of course rather suspicious.

Fix by moving `func()` to *above* `main()`, so the definition is seen before the call, or introduce a prototype before `main()`:

```
int * func();
```

Also, functions taking no arguments should be `(void)` in C, and [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).